# PoDoFo installation in Ubuntu(Linux)

Tags: podofo

I compile and installed PoDoFo in Ubuntu. But /usr/include and /usr/lib doesn't have any entry. I need it to work with my programs. Could you please let me know by default where the header file and lib files are installed? And how I can installed them in /usr/include and /usr/lib?